# How to resize the widget in jquery gridly ?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery Gridly to drag and drop  widgets . In the documentation of jquery Gridly it is written that the plugin supports drag/drop and re-size.

[Example of jquery gridly](http://ksylvest.github.io/jquery-gridly/)

Can someone please let me know where I can find an example of re-sizing or give me a hint how to implement it.

You can check the following codepen code and show me how the reseizing is done on the blocks using jquery gridly.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/jbsurveyer/pen/fbAcr)

```
<div class="gridly">
  <div class="brick small"></div>
  <div class="brick small"> <span style='color:white; font-size:18px;'>Drag and drop this block where you want it!</div>
  <div class="brick large"><img style="margin:20px" src='http://lorempixel.com/150/150/animals'></div>
  <div class="brick large"><img style="margin:20px" src='http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports'></div>
  <div class="brick small"></div>
  <div class="brick small"></div>
  <div class="brick large"><img style="margin:20px" src='http://placebear.com/150/150'></div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

jQuery("#list9").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager9',{add:false,del:false,edit:false,position:'right'});
jQuery("#m1").click( function() {       var s;      s = jQuery("#list9").jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');        alert(s);   });
jQuery("#m1s").click( function() {jQuery("#list9").jqGrid('setSelection',"13");
});
  
Get Selected id'sSelect(Unselect) row 13

Comment: I don't understand what this code does? Can you please add it one the codepen so I see what it does

Comment: I actually need jquery gridly.Thank you though